# Запрос, возвращающий последний сгенерированый ID из определённой таблицы

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Как написать запрос к базе MYSQL, чтобы вернулся последний сгенерированый ID из определённой таблицы? Пробовал использовать функцию `mysql_insert_id()`, но в результате почему-то выдаёт не то число, которое у меня в `phpmyadmin`, а большее. Как обозначить, чтобы выборка была из нужной таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно уловил суть вопроса, то можно так:

```
SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM table
```

Comment: В принципе да! Ранее задавал этот вопрос, только немного с другой стороны и получил снова такой же ответ. и такое бывает! Спасибо

Comment: `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`
такой запрос удобно использовать если id не целочисленый...

Answer (score 0):

Ну обычно **mysql_insert_id()** узают в PHP и он возвращает последний, только что вставленный ID в таблицу, а чтобы вернуть *последний сгенерированый ID из определённой таблицы* тут уж можно и это использовать.

> SELECT max(id) as maxid FROM table

А так с какой целью ты используешь это? Обычно такое нужно при парсинге какого-нибудь документа со вставкой в БД, там иерархическая структура, многоуровневая, чтобы правильно всё вставилось в БД.